# Where to download previous version of .net core sdk?

Tags: .net-core

We have a project that uses `.net core sdk 1.0.0-preview2-003121`.

Currently, I'm setting up a CI server to do automatic builds. In the server, I'm getting this error because the .net core sdk that is installed is not the same as the one in the project.

**ERROR**

`preview2-003121 which is not installed or cannot be found under the path C:\Program Files\dotnet.`

I did a command line check `dotnet --version` and it gave me `1.0.0-preview2-003131`

Where can I download older versions of the .net core sdk? I have tried the following links and they give me the latest version for the download

- https://github.com/dotnet/cli
- https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md

Answer (score 21):

This article explains how to install the correct .net core version. HTH.
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/06/dotnet-netcore-versions.html

I was able to just get away with following

1. download https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/preview/Binaries/1.0.0-preview2-003121/dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview2-003121.zip
2. copy 1.0.0-preview2-003121 directory inside dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview2-003121.zip\sdk
3. paste in C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk

Note: I had newer sdk version already installed(1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)

**---Update---**

Official download location is https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md as mentioned by vinicius-paiva and manoj-attal.

Answer (score 16):

If you are looking to download specific version of .Net core, you can download from here. It worked for me.

[Dot Net Core Download Archive List](https://github.com/dotnet/core/tree/main/release-notes/download-archives)

Comment: thanx @manoj Attal. I guess this should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Link is dead now.

Answer (score 0):

Install using the [chocolatey packages](https://chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetcore-sdk), of course.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is a late answer, it might help others.

Check these out.

1. https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/download-archive.md
2. https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all

Answer (score 0):

```
winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.6.0.125
```

Replace 6.0.125 with whatever version you need.