# How to install old version of dotnet version in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core

The currently guide to install `dotnet` in `linux` here:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu16-04/sdk-2.1.300

It will install the latest version of dotnet in linux, but my previous application running at dotnet version `1.1.2` so **How can I install the old version of dotnet core and run it?**

Thanks.

Comment: 2.1.300 SDK installation has no impact on your 1.1.2 runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get .NET Core 1.1.4 via `sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.1.4` instead of `sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1`. Try `apt-cache search dotnet` to see all the SDK (`sdk`, `-dev`) and other .NET Core packages that are available for your distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions it seems we have to manually download them.  For example, I needed to get 2.1.403.  Here's where to do that:

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md

Originally found via this Q&A:

[Where to download previous version of .net core sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521909/where-to-download-previous-version-of-net-core-sdk)

Be careful to only pull out the 'sdk' portion from the tar.gz, don't overwrite your newer `dotnet` executable!